# How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}x=1$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, derivatives, alternative-proof

How to prove that 
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}x=1?$$

I'm looking for a method besides L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: How do you prove $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$?

Comment: Rewrite as $\frac{1}{\cos x}\frac{\sin x}{x}$. (I am assuming here that you have dealt in class with $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$.)

Comment: Power series will also work.

Comment: @Potato No! I'm not allowed to use power series too

Comment: @SohamChowdhury I use  L-hopital's rule to prove it!

Comment: The limit in André's answer can be computing without power series or L'hopital's rule.

Comment: Have you seen the geometric / pictorial proofs?

Comment: What is your definition of $\tan$?  This will affect the answer to the question...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Strong hint:** $$\displaystyle \lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\tan (x)}{x}\right)=\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\tan (x)-0}{x-0}\right)=\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\tan(x)-\tan(0)}{x-0}\right)=\cdots$$

Comment: Nice alt method, +1!

Comment: that's creative (:

Comment: that's creative:)

Comment: Hmm. How do you find the derivative of $\tan x$ evaluated at  $x=0$ without knowing the value of  $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}{\sin x\over x}$?

Comment: @DavidMitra I guess this answer assumes a proper definition of the trigonometric functions, i.e., non-geometric definitions.

Comment: @DavidMitra: I think what Git Gud means is to use the derivative of $\tan x = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$

Comment: @Alex That's what I mean. I think you missed Mitra's point, though.  He's implying that in order to know that the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$, etc, you need to know before hand that $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin (x)}{x}=1$.

Comment: @GitGud: perhaps, I didn't quite see this. Your proof is still pretty creative.

Comment: @Alex Well, it really depends on the definition of $\sin$to assert wether my answer is a valid proof. And thanks.

Comment: I've added the derivatives tag to validate your answer ;-).

Comment: @julien $\ddot \smile$

Comment: IMO, this is a dead end. In the first place, it can be seen as an instance of L'Hospital. But more importantly, it requires the derivative of the tangent, which is defined… as this limit. If you take the derivative of the tangent for granted, this is equivalent to taking the limits of $\sin x/x$ and $\tan x/x$ for granted.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Not if you define $\sin$ and $\cos$ by their power series and $\tan$ as the ration between them.

Comment: @GitGud: that's right, the power series gives all derivatives at $0$.

Answer (score 15):

Consider the unit circle with center $O$. Let $A$ be a fixed point on the circumference. Let $X$ be a point on the circumference such that $\angle AOX = x$.

Let the tangent at $X$ intersect $OA$ extended at $B$. Since $\angle OXB = 90^\circ$ hence $BX = \tan x$.

Then, the area of the sector $OAX$ is $\frac{x\times 1^2}{2}$ and the area of the triangle $OXB$ is $\frac{1 \times \tan x}{2}$. It is clear that as $X$ tends towards $A$, the limit of these areas is $1$.

[image]

Comment: GeoGebra, right?

Comment: @SohamChowdhury Yup :) I'm learning to use it; this is a screenshot of it. Apparrantly there is a way to share a web version which allows others to play around with the figures you draw.

Comment: +1 I voted for this one Calvin because for the student who are facing this limit, we should apply geometric approach. Thanks for sharing us this way.

Answer (score 6):

$$\tan { x } =x+\frac { { x }^{ 3 } }{ 3 } +\frac { 2{ x }^{ 5 } }{ 15 } +\cdots \\ \frac { \tan { x }  }{ x } =\frac { x+\frac { { x }^{ 3 } }{ 3 } +\frac { 2{ x }^{ 5 } }{ 15 } +\cdots  }{ x } =1+\frac { { x }^{ 2 } }{ 3 } +\frac { 2{ x }^{ 4 } }{ 15 } +\cdots \\ \lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \left( \frac { \tan { x }  }{ x }  \right)  } =1$$Or for the geometric proof see:http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Sine_of_X_over_X/Geometric_Proof

Comment: Simplest proof, +1

Answer (score 6):

In order to find the derivative of $\sin x$, many calculus courses start by proving, sort of, that 
$$\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1.\tag{1}$$

If that is already taken as "known" in your course, note that unless $\cos x=0$, we have
$$\frac{\tan x}{x}=\frac{1}{\cos x}\frac{\sin x}{x}.$$
Now we can take the limit. Use (1) and the fact that $\cos x$ is continuous at $0$ and therefore $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\cos x=1$.

Comment: You were a tiny bit faster!

Comment: @SohamChowdhury Check the comments to the question.

Comment: @GitGud: Thanks for improving the TeX.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following circle with a regular $n$ side polygon inside:
[image]

We know that if the polygon have more sides the its perimeter will get closer to the perimeter of circle. $$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { Perimeter\ of\ polygon }{ Perimeter\ of\ circle }  } =\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { 2n\sin { \frac { \pi  }{ n }  }  }{ 2\pi  }  } =\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { \sin { \frac { \pi  }{ n }  }  }{ \frac { \pi  }{ n }  }  }=1. $$ Assume $x=\frac { \pi  }{ n } $ then we get $$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { x }  }{ x }  } =1.$$We already know $\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \cos x } =1$, therefore $$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \tan { x }  }{ x }  } =1.$$

Comment: If you use a polygon external to the circle you get $\tan x$ directly.

Comment: @MarkBennet Ah yes, I didn't think. Thank you.

Comment: It is not correct to write "say $x=\pi n^{-1}$".

Comment: @PeterTamaroff the word "Say" is not correct?

Comment: @newzad No, I mean mathematically. You're replacing a sequence of rational numbers by a limit which comprises "all" real numbers. That is a big leap, and should be justified.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Ok, I got what you mean.

Comment: @newzad Ah, sorry, of course, but I think you know what I meant. The statement $f(x)\to \ell \;\;;x\to a$ is equivalent to $f(a_n)\to \ell$ for every $a_n\to a$; $a_n\neq a$.

Answer (score 2):

You could expand $tan(x)$ as a power series and then divide all terms by $x$ and then take the limit?

Comment: Sorry, just seen that you're not allowed to use the power series.

Answer (score 2):

Here's mine!

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x}$$
$$= \lim_{x \to 0} \sec x\frac{\sin x}{x}$$
$$= \bigg(\lim_{x \to 0}\sec x\bigg) * \bigg(\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}\bigg)$$
$$= \bigg(\lim_{x \to 0}\cos x\bigg)^{-1} * 1 $$
$$= 1^{-1} * 1$$
$$= 1$$ :)

Answer (score 1):

This limit is proven in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151). That answer was in response to the question of how to show
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1
$$
However, since $\cos(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, the two questions are related:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)}{x}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{\cos(x)}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\\
&=\frac1{\cos(0)}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\\[6pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at it is to consider an angle subtended by two finite lines, both of magnitude r, where the angle between them is x (we take x to be small). If you draw this out, you can see there are "3 areas" you can consider. One is the area enclosed with a straight line joining the two end points, an arc and lastly considering a right-angled triangle. Sorry I cant provide a diagram, I'm new to maths.stackexchange :)

you get the following result

1/2*r^2sinx < 1/2*r^2x < 1/2*r^2tanx for small x, with simplication we get

sinx < x < tanx divide by tanx yeilds

cosx < x/tanx < 1 taking the limit as x goes to 0, (which we can do as we took x to be small)

we get 1 < x/tanx < 1, by squeeze theorem this tells us the limit of as x >>0 for x/tanx is 1. Now the limit of tans/x as x approaches 0 will be the reciprocal of this. I should mention I am assuming early foundational results regarding limits in an Analysis course. Hence, the limit is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Using L'Hôpital rule, we'll see
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\mathrm{tan}(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left (\mathrm{cos}^{2}(x)  \right )^{-1}}{1}=\lim_{x\to\infty} 1-\mathrm{sin}^{2}(x)=\dots
$$

Comment: The question specifies "other than L'hopital"

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan (x)}{x} = \frac{d}{dx}\tan(0)=\sec^2(0)=1$$

This, I find, is the simplest method of showing it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/448210/55235).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

We know that if the polygon have more sides the its perimeter will get closer to the perimeter of circle.
 $$\frac{HB}{R}=\tan \left(\frac{360}{2n}\right)=\tan \left(\frac{π}{n}\right)\\AB=2HB=2R\tan \left(\frac{π}{n}\right)$$
Perimeter of polygon = $nAB=2nR\tan \left(\frac{π}{n}\right) \\$

Perimeter of circle  = $2π R $

Now when $n → \infty $ $$ \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{\text{Perimeter of  
 polygon}}{\text{Perimeter of circle}}=1$$
$$\lim_{n → \infty } \frac{2n R \tan \left(\frac{π}{n}\right)}{2 π R }=1$$
$$\lim_{n → \infty } \frac{n  \tan \left(\frac{π}{n}\right)}{ π  }=1$$
$$\lim_{n → \infty } \frac{\tan \left(\frac{π}{n}\right)}{\frac{π}{n}}=1$$

Obviously $\frac{π}{n} →  0$ name as $x$ so $$ \lim_{n → \infty } \frac{\tan \left(\frac{π}{n}\right)}{\frac{π}{n}}=\lim_{x → 0 } \frac{\tan \left(x\right)}{x}=1$$

Comment: Nice geometrical solution. Thanks

Comment: thanks mahdi , are you in sharif ?

Comment: what is down vote for  ? (I don't think it's duplicated )

Comment: Such geometric proofs always seem artificial to me because you need to rigorously show the equivalence of the concepts/properties of geometry and calculus. In particular, what does it mean to take a polygon "in the limit" ? And how are the sine/cosine of geometry equivalent to those of calculus ?