# Taking the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} x \tan(1/x)$ without L'Hopital's Rule

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I have to evaluate the following without L'Hopital's rule

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\tan(1/x)$$

I can simplify this to be $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\sin(1/x)$$

because 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \cos(1/x) = 1$$

However, after that, I'm totally lost. L'Hopital's rule seems like my only option. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Related: [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}x=1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448207/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-tan-xx-1) And, of course, the famous question [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are allowed to use the fact that $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}=1$, then setting $t=\frac{1}{x}$ yields
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}=1$$

Comment: Now that is an interesting solution I hadn't thought of. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

After a change of variables, this is just

$$\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac 1 t \tan t$$

which you can evaluate via the definition of the derivative of tangent, or geometrically prove that $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac 1 t \sin t = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x\tan\frac{1}{x}$$
Let $t=\frac{1}{x}$, then
$$\lim\limits_{t\to 0} \frac{\tan t}{t}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin t}{t\cos t}$$
$$=\left(\lim\limits_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin t}{t}\right)\left(\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{\cos t}\right)=1$$